# trouble shooting unstable os

Tags: server, live-usb, fsck, smart

I like to port forward my jupyter notebook from my remote ubuntu server to my local laptop.  So I'm running the jupyter notebook server on the ubuntu server and forwarding it to my local laptop.  I often leave the notebook server up for days, even weeks at a time.  I have a mysql database running on the server as well, that gets updated throughout the day.  I've been having more issues lately with my server seeming to lock up, where I can't ssh in to it, and when I connect directly it displays repetitive messages some involving long strings of sequences of numbers and letters.  I've been having to solve the issue with hard shutdowns, booting from live media and running fsck -y on the partitions for my boot efi and os.  I'm wondering if the issues could be related to a process running to update the mysql db and maxing out all available temp directory room.  It seems like I've had conflicts in the past where jupyter notebook and mysql were fighting over temp directory/ram.  Also I've had recent issues when working with LLM and downloading the weights for some of the larger models, it maxed out my available temp/ram, then the os became unstable until booting from live media and running fsck -y on os and boot partitions.  I know that's a lot all rolled together but is it sounding any alarm bells for anyone?

also besides booting from live media and running "fsck -y" are there any additional clean up/repair steps anyone can suggest like running smart on the os drive?

I ran

```
sudo smartctl /dev/nvme1n1 -x | less
```

on the nvme1n1 drive that my os is installed on but didn't see anything out of the ordinary.  It said it "passed".

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've not provided any clues as to what release of what Ubuntu Server you have installed (Ubuntu Core [Server]? or Ubuntu Server? and what release of that product).  You also gave no clues as to *file-system* as `fsck` is not the correct command for all file-systems (but is for others so it may or may not have been the correct command for your *unstated* file-system(s)).  If a system locks up unexpectedly, I'd first work out what you're running (you only stated Ubuntu Server) then explore OS/system logs for clues (`journalctl` which can be view even after reboot), check hardware health etc..

Comment: "*it displays repetitive messages some involving long strings of sequences of numbers and letters*" Useful to record an example to show us. We might recognize it.